# Server permissions for shiny downloadhandeller()

Tags: r, server, shiny, permissions, googlevis

I am trying to setup a shiny app that can download html plots from the googleViz package. The code works on my machine, but when I move it to the server I get the following message when testing the download...

"The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator."

I am struggling to figure out what the IT staff, that set up the server, need to do to fix the problem - I know nothing about servers and they know nothing about R.

I built a small example app [here](http://wicshiny.iiasa.ac.at/download-test/) to demonstrate the problem, based on the following `ui.R`

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

# user interface
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("googleVis on Shiny"),
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("dataset", label = "Choose a dataset:",
                    choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
        downloadButton('download_gvis', label = 'Download')
    ),
    mainPanel(
        htmlOutput("view")
    )
))
```

and `server.R`

```
library(googleVis)
library(webshot)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # data set from user 
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "rock" = rock,
           "pressure" = pressure,
           "cars" = cars)
  })

  # plot of data set from user
  my_plot <- reactive({
    gvisScatterChart(datasetInput(),
                     options=list(title=paste('Data:',input$dataset)))
  })

  # render plot of data set from user
  output$view <- renderGvis({
    my_plot()
  })

  # download plot of data set from user
  output$download_gvis <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "test.png",
    content = function(file) {
      g <- my_plot()

      # print to html file
      print(g, file = "gg.html")

      # take a webshot of html file and save as png
      webshot(
        url = "gg.html", 
        file = "output.png", 
        delay = 2
      )

      # send output file to downloadHandler
      file.copy("output.png", file)

      # delete files
      file.remove("gg.html")
      file.remove("output.png")
    }
  )
})
```

I think the code breaks at `print(g, file = "gg.html")` in the server script. The`gg.html` file never appears in the server directory (on my local machine I see it pop up in the directory view of RStudio).

Comment: If you have write issues in folder, I don't see any problem with the `print`. I think the issue is with `webshot` that can't access/browse local file. Should there be a web server on the server, you may write file in a temporary subdirectory and browse full URL.

Comment: The Shiny server will run your apps as a user called `shiny` which likely does not have the correct permissions to write a file. You can ask your it staff to add those to the `shiny` user. 

Another way, perhaps, would be to write the files to a temp file created by in your shiny `server` function (unsure this will work). `path <- tempfile(pattern = "", fileext = ".html")`.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions... the temp file worked